# controls doesn't show if run on a background thread ( c# winform)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a form (**complexForm** in the code) with multiple controls which takes some time to load. So I decided to put in in a separate thread in order to decrease initial loading time. Everything works fine except the label control on the wait form ( **Form1** in the code) doesn't show up initially; just a flash of a sec before Form1 went off. So my question is, why  doesn't the label control show up?

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        var wait = new Form1(); //simple form with a label control with text "please wait"
        wait.Show();
        var complexUI = new complexForm();// this takes long time to load
        wait.Dispose();// it will go off even without this method
        // MessageBox.Show("loaded");
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new main());

}
```

Comment: If you are using more than one `thread`, why are you setting the `ApartmentState` to single-threading (`[STAThread]` and `ApartmentState.STA`)?

Comment: What you want to achieve? `var complexUI = new complexForm();// this takes long time to load` What operation in the complexForm constructor is cause long load?

Comment: actually I have DevExpress richeditcontrols with ribbonbar in it which takes long to load. Please refer to this URL   http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q406398.aspx

Comment: Displaying UI on another thread requires pumping a message loop.  Application.Run() is required.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this. It'll end in tears. Only ever create UI controls from the UI thread - that's the thread that owns the message pump, which is crucial to proper operation.

The right solution to this is to create a Splash Screen which is shown while your main window is initialising.

There's quite a few threads on Stack Overflow about how to create a splash screen.

Comment: I am aware of the splash screen approach. just curious about this thread  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q406398.aspx